# What is the significance of caddr_t and when is it used?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

Can somebody please tell me:

1. What is `caddr_t` ?
2. When is it used ?
3. How it is different from `void*` ?
4. When to use `void*` and when to use `caddr_t` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "saves a cast"? :) At least on Linux x64 it is eventually `char*` (after first going through `__kernel_caddr_t`). In that regard it works as an *opaque type*.

Comment: Not clear from what you say :-( What is "saves a cast"????? Why not then directly use char*. I don't think it is that way. Mainly i have seen this used in memory allocation related things. Especially using mmap.

Comment: http://computer-programming-forum.com/47-c-language/f3a1576887d6652f.htm

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`caddr_t` is a legacy BSD type associated with some low level calls like `mmap`, and it should never be used in modern code. It was rejected by the POSIX standard. The standardized `mmap` uses `void *`.

Comment: You said: "caddr_t is a legacy BSD type associated with some low level calls like mmap", you have slipped to mention the reason for it's association, when simultaneously `void*` also existed.

Comment: It was probably created before `void *` existed, though I don't have a reference for that claim. In any case it's irrelevant now. It's not part of any modern standard, should not be used in new code, and should be fixed in old code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand your point, but can you please post a link/reference which says: "caddr_t is obsolete and instead void* must be used" ?

Comment: Simply look at POSIX which does not mention `caddr_t` anywhere. In particular, the documentation for `mmap`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html has the correct prototype with `void *`. You can search the rest of the standard for `caddr_t` if you like but you won't find it because it doesn't exist.

Comment: I second that. While perhaps not in the POSIX `mmap` signature, *it is* used a good bit in the [Linux kernel](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/ident?i=caddr_t). (I understand this is a "specific domain", but...)

Comment: Linux kernel is not a good reference for sane use of types... :-)

Comment: @R..: I am sorry, but do you think not having mentioned in POSIX man for an API `mmap`, mean that it is obsolete???? Infact i saw that man page prior to posting my query. If it is obsolete it must be mentioned somewhere...and the fact is i am unable to google it to get a proof. please refer to `efence` code.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Are you trying to get an answer or are you trying to start an argument? The classic place `caddr_t` was used was as an argument and return type for `mmap` (and perhaps certain other functions like `brk`) in place of `void *`. This usage is not reflected in modern standards or operating systems. What more do you want me to say?

Comment: @R: It's not about arguing 'R', the place where we guys work, requires substantial proof and supporting docs, before we utter a word, or write a single line of code, and one faulty code going in the products costs much and we ought to be more careful because we write code for embeddded systems and real-time systems for CE-Linux and it's not x86 but ARM. So we have to be very careful.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 [When in Rome, do as the Romans do...](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/when-in-rome-do-as-the-romans-do.html)

Comment: @pst: That's what i was trying to do :)

Comment: just as a side note, the linux kernel isnt the only place. I just found it as an argument to osx's `ptrace` function.

Answer (score 3):

`caddr_t` was used as a pointer to a core address. I used it in SVR4 when I needed to access kernel structures from user space (having used mmap to access `/dev/kmem`). Even when "`/proc`" existed, the ps command still used mmap of the kernel to start walking the process table. As everybody states it was superseded by void *.