# expected specifier-qualifier-list before "typedef"

Tags: c, typedef

I have an error that I don't know how to solve, which is :

```
expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'typedef'
```

at this line :

```
typedef caddr_t ipsec_policy_t;
```

Can someone explain me why and how to solve this please ?

Comment: Did you include the file where `caddr_t` is declared?

Comment: Node that `caddr_t` is not a standard type, neither in C nor in POSIX.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608175/what-does-this-error-mean-error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-typ

Comment: Well, this is strange because when i replace this "typedef" definition by "#define ipsec_policy_t char*" (because i initialize caddr_t as a char pointer), then it works ! and now i have another error which let me think that the error comes from higher : i have an error here : `extern void pfkey_sadump (struct sadb_msg *);` in my header file, with the same error message but with 'extern' and not 'typedef' in the message.

Answer (score 1):

```
//A.h
typedef unsigned char uchar;

//B.h
struct B {
    #include "A.h"
   ...
}
```

I met this problem just now. It's work when I move the include statement from the internal struct B.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know that `caddr_t` is a type. You may like to check that the appropriate typedef is in scope when this code is compiled. It is possible that you missed to include the appropriate header file.

Comment: I have an error that i don't understand : i created a simple 

`typedef int a;` 

and my console returns me this error :

`error : expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'typedef'`.

The console knows the `int` type because i tried a simple `int b` just before and the console did not give me an error !

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the compiler does not know what `caddr_t` is. Make sure the appropriate declaration or include is present before your typedef.

Answer (score 0):

This one is expected error. compiler not found `caddr_t` type. It's because it's not standard data type. It may be declared in some header file or else where which is you forgot to include.

After some googling found some links related to it.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=caddr_t

[What is the significance of caddr_t and when is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381526/what-is-the-significance-of-caddr-t-and-when-is-it-used)

Answer (score 0):

> when i replace this "typedef" definition by "#define ipsec_policy_t
>   char*" (because i initialize caddr_t as a char pointer), then it works
>   ! and now i have another error which let me think that the error comes
>   from higher

Right! The cause of the error lies above this line, so look before it at the source or perhaps at the preprocessor output.