# Wireless ESSID and Signal Strength in C using wireless.h

Tags: c, wireless, ioctl

I currently have an application which obtains the essid and signal strength using a popen(nmcli...) that I'm trying to switch to pure C using wireless.h and ioctl. Obtaining the ESSID is easy enough, however trying to get the strength/quality through SIOCGIWSTATS keeps giving me an "Operation not supported" error. Can anyone spot what I've done wrong, or maybe it's just my wireless driver that doesn't actually support SIOCGIWSTATS?

Please ignore the use of global variables, it's just temporary while I debug the current issue.

Thanks,

Haydn.

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <ifaddrs.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <linux/wireless.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>

    char ifname[IFNAMSIZ];
    char essid[IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE+1];
    struct iwreq wrq;
    struct iw_statistics *iwstats;
    int sock;


    int findWifi() {
      struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;

      if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1) {
        perror("Error getting interface addresses");
        return -1;
      }

      for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
        strncpy(wrq.ifr_name, ifa->ifa_name, IFNAMSIZ);

        if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
          perror("Error opening INET socket");
        }

        if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWNAME, &wrq) == 0) {
          printf("IF: %s\n", wrq.ifr_name);
          strcpy(ifname, wrq.ifr_name);
          freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
          return sock;
        }
      }
      freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
      return 0;
    }

    int wifiInfo() {
      wrq.u.essid.pointer = essid;
      if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWESSID, &wrq) == -1) {
        perror("Can't open socket to obtain essid");
        return(-1);
      }

      printf("ESSID is %s\n", wrq.u.essid.pointer);

      memset(&iwstats, 0, sizeof(iwstats));

      wrq.u.data.pointer = (caddr_t) &iwstats;
      wrq.u.data.length = sizeof(&iwstats);
      wrq.u.data.flags = 1;

      // ERROR HERE...
      if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWSTATS, &wrq) == -1) {
        perror("Can't open socket to obtain iwstats");
        return(-1);
      }

      return(0);
    }

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
      findWifi();
      wifiInfo();
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone spot what I've done wrong, or maybe it's just my wireless driver that doesn't actually support SIOCGIWSTATS?

Your code looks good or at least very close, although this line needs double check:

```
wrq.u.data.pointer = (caddr_t) &iwstats;
```

This does not compile on Ubuntu 16.04 because `caddr_t` is undeclared. This happens even after adding `<linux/types.h> and <sys/types.h>`.

Googling a bit seems to indicate this `caddr_t` is BSD-specific, and you're advised not using it:

[What is the significance of caddr_t and when is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381526/what-is-the-significance-of-caddr-t-and-when-is-it-used)

---

For the second part of your question, you may be able to check if the Wifi driver actually supports `SIOCGIWSTATS` by using common tool like `iwconfig`.

Comment: Thanks, the caddr_t actually came from the wireless tools code, for example: https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools/blob/master/wireless_tools/iwlist.c#L1615, (struct iw_statistics*) should work instead. Interesting point re: iwconfig, as a non-priv user I get no quality listed but I do as root, running my wifiInfo as root I get an "argument list too long" error instead of unsupported so that could be something to look at.

Comment: that wireless tool is obsolete; consider using wpa_supplicant instead

Comment: @artm: can [wpa_supplicant](https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant) be used to scan wireless networks just as wireless tools iwlist scanning option does ? Could not find how in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Thanks artm for suggesting iwconfig, that pointed me to it not working as non-root. With minor changes the code now works as root (although needs some tidying, e.g: removal of the globals, checking iwstats.qual.updated is the  right value etc). I'll have to see why non-root can't run it but that's a separate question.

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <ifaddrs.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <linux/wireless.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>

    char ifname[IFNAMSIZ];
    char essid[IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE+1];
    struct iwreq wrq;
    struct iw_statistics iwstats;
    int sock;


    int findWifi() {
      struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;

      if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1) {
        perror("Error getting interface addresses");
        return -1;
      }

      for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
        strncpy(wrq.ifr_name, ifa->ifa_name, IFNAMSIZ);

        if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
          perror("Error opening INET socket");
        }

        if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWNAME, &wrq) == 0) {
          printf("IF: %s\n", wrq.ifr_name);
          strcpy(ifname, wrq.ifr_name);
          freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
          return sock;
        }
      }
      freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
      return 0;
    }

    int wifiInfo() {
      wrq.u.essid.pointer = essid;
      if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWESSID, &wrq) == -1) {
        perror("Can't open socket to obtain essid");
        return(-1);
      }

      printf("ESSID is %s\n", wrq.u.essid.pointer);

      memset(&iwstats, 0, sizeof(iwstats));

      wrq.u.data.pointer = &iwstats;
      wrq.u.data.length = sizeof(struct iw_statistics);
      wrq.u.data.flags = 1;

      if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWSTATS, &wrq) == -1) {
        perror("Can't open socket to obtain iwstats");
        return(-1);
      }

      printf("Signal level is %d\n", iwstats.qual.updated);
      return(0);
    }

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
      findWifi();
      wifiInfo();
      return 0;
    }
```